# ODM Query Builder: Is there an "inverse in" operator, or equivalent operation?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, odm

In my synfony 2 project, I'm filtering search results using a query builder. In my MongoDB i have some values in an array.

[Query Bulider](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html) has the "in" operator that allows to query for values that equal one of many in an array. I wanted to perform the opposite operation, i.e. given a single value, query for entries in the data base that contain an array, that contains my value.

For instance, say I have this entry in my MongoDB:

```
{
  "_id": 123,
  "name": "John",
  "countries_visited":
  [
    "Australia"
    "Bulgaria",
    "Canada"
  ]
}
```

And I want to query my database for persons who have visited "Canada". Right now, I'm using the `where` attribute as follows, but I'm looking for a better way to do this.

```
        $qb->field('countries_visited')->where("function(){
            return this.indexOf(".$countryName.") > -1
        }");
```

edit: 
The `in` and `notIn` operator receives an array as parameter and compares it against a single value in MongoDB. I need to provide a single parameter and apply it to an array field in MongoDB, hence "inverse in". I guess I need a `contains` operator if there's such a thing.

Comment: I would have thought `notIn()` would be what you're after :)

Comment: No, please read the whole explanation first, not just the title.

Comment: I did and I don't understand it

Comment: Adam Elsodaney, I added a summary in the end of my question, trying to explain it better. How would you query for all people who visited Canada?

Comment: It only now occurred to me, but if I could name the operator I need, it would me "contains". ``$qb->field('countries_visited')->contains('canada')``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting, MongoDB takes care of this automatically. If querying for a single value against an array field, Mongo will assume you want the check the array if it contains the value.

Taken from the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-an-array-element):

> **Match an Array Element**
>
> Equality matches can specify a single element in the array to match. These specifications match if the array contains at least one element with the specified value.

So you should be able to do

```
$users = $dm->getRepository('User')->findOneBy([
    'countries_visited' => 'Canada'
]);
```

or

```
$qb->field('countries_visited')->equals('Canada');
```

Comment: Equals operator will work in an array? Will try and bring back results. Thanks.

Comment: It totally does. As a side note, this will only travel arrays by one level and won't work with arrays inside arrays.